# Pine Script - Determining delta between three time intervals

Tags: pine-script, stock, trading

Working with Pine Script and TradingView

Essentially I have three indicators that all plot on my chart. Instead of plotting all three, I'd like to combine them and have a single flag plot whenever they are all within a certain amount of time apart. My thinking is that whenever an indicator is triggered, it will assign the current timestamp to a variable. If the same variable triggers back to back, the timestamp will continuously update with the more recent time. What I would like is for if all three variables are within X hours of each other, it will signal a flag to post.

A) Is is possible to assign timestamps to variables?

B) Is it possible to determine a delta between three given timestamps and trigger a plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone more experienced than me might provide an alternative opinion, but in general I do not recommend using timestamps. Use bars and create conditions using barssince.

Say you're on a thirty minute chart, and want triggers within 3 hours.

```
recent(_cond, _bars) =>
    recent_cond = barssince(_cond) <= _bars
    recent_cond

condtionA = ...
conditionB = ...
conditionC = ...
condtionAll = recent(conditionA, 6) and recent(conditionB, 6) and recent(conditionC, 6)
```